# Postgresql. Find nearest string pattern match

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

There is table with the next structure

```
Table tab1
(
range text,
col1 text
)
```

Data example:
123, some text

1234, some text

12345, some text

I would like to find data in this table by the next algorithm
I have input string to find the most nearest string matching (from the beginning of string)

For example:

'123456789' should find row with range 12345

'123409861' should find row with range 1234

'123609862' should find row with range 123

So idea is to find range that contains the most count of similar symbols (from the beginning of string) with input string

The main point to do it without cycles (trim last symbol and find string)

My current code:

```
DECLARE v_string text default p_string; -- p_string - input param
DECLARE v_row_cnt int default 0;

BEGIN
    
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp;
    CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp
    (
        "range" varchar(15),
        col1 text
    );

    LOOP
        INSERT INTO tmp
        SELECT
            "range", 
            col1
        FROM tab1
        WHERE "range" = v_string;
    
        GET DIAGNOSTICS v_row_cnt = ROW_COUNT;
    
        IF v_row_cnt = 0 AND v_string <> '' THEN 
            v_string := substr(v_string, 1, length(v_string) - 1);
        ELSE 
            exit;
        END IF;

    END LOOP;

    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT
        "range", 
        col1
    FROM tmp;

END
```

Comment: `select * from tab1 where '123409861' like "range"||'%'`?

Comment: @Looks right but I would like to add 

order by LENGTH("range") desc
limit 1

at the end

Comment: Yes, sure, it have a sense.